# How is binary search applicable here (since the values are not monotonic)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I am solving a LeetCode problem [Search in Rotated Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/), in order to learn Binary Search better.  The problem statement is:

> There is an integer array `nums` sorted in ascending order (with distinct values). Prior to being passed to your function, `nums` is possibly rotated at an unknown pivot index. For example, `[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]` might be rotated at pivot index `3` and become `[4,5,6,7,0,1,2]`. Given the array `nums` after the possible rotation and an integer `target`, return the index of `target` if it is in `nums`, or `-1` if it is not in `nums`.

With some online help, I came up with the solution below, which I mostly understand:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int l=0, r=nums.size()-1;
        
        while(l<r) {    // 1st loop; how is BS applicable here, since array is NOT sorted?
            int m=l+(r-l)/2;
            if(nums[m]>nums[r]) l=m+1;
            else r=m;
        }
        
        // cout<<"Lowest at: "<<r<<"\n";
        if(nums[r]==target) return r;   //target==lowest number
        int start, end;
        if(target<=nums[nums.size()-1]) {
            start=r;
            end=nums.size()-1;
        } else {
            start=0;
            end=r;
        }
        l=start, r=end;
        while(l<r) {
            int m=l+(r-l)/2;
            if(nums[m]==target) return m;
            if(nums[m]>target) r=m;
            else l=m+1;
        }
        
        return nums[l]==target ? l : -1;
    }
};
```

**My question**: Are we searching over a **parabola** in the first while loop, trying to find the lowest point of a parabola, unlike a linear array in traditional binary search?  Are we finding the **minimum of a convex function**? I understand how the values of `l`, `m` and `r` change leading to the right answer - but I do not fully follow how we can be guaranteed that `if(nums[m]>nums[r])`, our lowest value would be on the right.

Comment: *but how is this correct* -- Step in the code using a debugger.

Comment: *I know exactly it works, but not why it works.* -- Step in the code with a debugger.  That is one of the reasons to use a debugger, to understand *why* code works.

Comment: *I have the doubt because,* -- Then this is a pencil and paper question, and not one of C++.  The goal is to not write a single line of C++ code until you know exactly the purpose of every variable, function call, `if` and `for` statement, etc. is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, could you please answer my edit - _that_ is my main question: "Are we searching over a parabola in the first while loop, trying to find the lowest point of a parabola, unlike a linear array in traditional binary search?"  I understand the rest.

Comment: The comment section is for comments, not for answers.  The main comment is this -- you wrote C++ code, and you do not understand why it works.  That should never be the case -- any C++ code you write, you must understand it.  Writing code goes from pencil and paper to implementation -- you don't write the implementation having doubts, and then have more doubts after you see it working.

Comment: The reason binary search works in the first loop is because we're not looking for a value, we're looking for a certain pattern of change between two values. The array is sorted enough to be able to determine where this change could possibly be based on a local binary decision rather than examining the whole array.

Comment: @ggorlen, thanks, so are we finding the minimum of a convex function in that case? I think what you call "a pattern" is actually a "convex function"?

Comment: I don't know what a convex function is.

Comment: @ggorlen, I am just referring [these notes](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse417/18wi/lectures/lec04-binary-search-3.pdf) from UW.   (Just search for "Minimum of a Convex Function"). Since we are updating the values of `l` and `r` based on `if(nums[m]>nums[r])`, I think our search space is _parabolic_ (for e.g., the subarray `[8,1,2]`) and we aim to find the _lowest_ point of this parabolic space.

Comment: It is looking at the middle element, and making a decision which half to continue searching.  Thus the "binary search" is not one where it is searching a sorted list -- it is "binary" in that it is an "either this side or that side" approach to the problem.  No one, or very few persons who would solve this problem would know what a "convex function" is.  Just looking at the problem and applying simple logic.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yes, agreed.  I wanted to clarify my fundamental understanding, which is why I asked about the convex function.  I did realize this with a few examples, but I was not able to convince myself that this would work for all edge cases, until I thought about this as a convex function.  And then I just wanted some clarification that it indeed is.

Answer (score 1):

#### You actually skipped something important by “getting help”.

<sup>Once, when I was struggling to integrate something tricky for Calculus Ⅰ, I went for help and the advisor said, “Oh, I know how to do this” and solved it. I learned nothing from him. It took me another week of going over it (and other problems) myself to understand it sufficient that I could do it myself.</sup>

The purpose of these assignments is to solve the problem yourself. Even if your solution is faulty, you have learned more than simply reading and understanding the basics of one example problem someone else has solved.

#### In this particular case...

Since you already have a solution, let’s take a look at it: Notice that it contains ***two*** binary search loops. Why?

As you observed at the beginning, the offset shift makes the array *discontinuous* (not convex). However, *the subarrays either side of the discontinuity **remain monotonic**.*

<sup>Take a moment to convince yourself that this is true.</sup>

Knowing this, what would be a good way to find and determine which of the two subarrays to search?
Hints:

- A binary search as  ( ***n*** ⟶ ∞ )   is   O(log n)
- O(log n) ≡ O(2 log n)

I should also observe to you that the prompt gives as *example* an arithmetic progression with a common difference of 1, but the prompt itself imposes no such restriction. All it says is that you start with a strictly increasing sequence (no duplicate values). You could have as input `[19 74 512 513 3 7 12]`.

- Does the supplied solution handle this possibility?
- Why or why not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but IMHO it misunderstands the question: "the subarrays either side of the discontinuity remain monotonic" - this seems true _after_ the first loop has _finished_ - not at an intermediate stage of the loop.  If you consider `[4,5,6,7,8,1,2]`, then at an _intermediate_ stage, when `m=7`, the right side `[8,1,2]` is _not_ monotonic.  My question specifically is, what _guarantees_ us at this point that the least value (`1`) is on the right (unlike in case of traditional binary search where the values are **all** either increasing or decreasing).

Comment: Sure, a few examples help us see it, but I am looking for some kind of proof/guarantee.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the answer. If you just draw your array you can have a very simple geometric proof. Look at the differences in the two loops to see how it works.